# More than 19 IF Statements in a Formula in a calculated column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, limitations

I have the following formula in a calculated column which contains 19 IF statements.

I cannot add any more but I need 6 more. Any ideas to solve this.

```
=IF(AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Insignificant"),"Low",IF(AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Minor"),"Low",IF(AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Moderate"),"Low",IF(AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Major"),"Medium",IF(AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Catastrophic"),"Medium",IF(AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Insignificant"),"Low",IF(AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Minor"),"Low",IF(AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Moderate"),"Medium",IF(AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Major"),"Medium",IF(AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Catastrophic"),"High",IF(AND(Likelihood="Possible",Consequence="Insignificant"),"Low",IF(AND(Likelihood="Possible",Consequence="Minor"),"Medium",IF(AND(Likelihood="Possible",Consequence="Moderate"),"High",IF(AND(Likelihood="Possible",Consequence="Major"),"High",IF(AND(Likelihood="Possible",Consequence="Catastrophic"),"High",IF(AND(Likelihood="Likely",Consequence="Insignificant"),"Medium",IF(AND(Likelihood="Likely",Consequence="Minor"),"Medium",IF(AND(Likelihood="Likely",Consequence="Moderate"),"High",IF(AND(Likelihood="Likely",Consequence="Major"),"High","")))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your formula like so:

```
=IF(
    OR(
        OR(
            OR(
                OR(
                  AND(Likelihood="Likely",Consequence="Insignificant"),
                  AND(Likelihood="Minor",Consequence="Possible")
                ),
                OR(
                  AND(Likelihood="Likely",Consequence="Minor"),
                  AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Moderate")
                )
            ),
            OR(
              AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Major"),
              AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Major")
            )
        ),
        AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Catastrophic")
    ),  
    "Medium",   
    
    IF( 
        OR(
            OR(
                OR(
                  AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Insignificant"),
                  AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Insignificant")
                ),
                OR(
                  AND(Likelihood="Possible",Consequence="Insignificant"),
                  AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Minor")
                )
            ),
            OR(
              AND(Likelihood="Rare",Consequence="Moderate"),
              AND(Likelihood="Unlikely",Consequence="Minor")
            )
        )
        , "Low"
        , "High"
    )
)
```

Essentially, you can avoid checking 7 "High" conditions explicitly. Instead, assume that if it's not "Low" or "Medium" - then it's definitely "High"

[image]